# Beginner: Scala type alias in Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala

Why does this code fail to compile with the error: not found: value Matrix?  From the documentation and some (possibly out of date) code examples this should work?

```
object TestMatrix extends App{  
type Row = List[Int]
type Matrix = List[Row]


val m = Matrix( Row(1,2,3),
                Row(1,2,3),
                Row(1,2,3)
              )


}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Matrix` denotes a type, but you are using it as a value.

When you do `List(1, 2, 3)`, you are actually calling `List.apply`, which is a factory method for `List`.

To fix your compiling error, you can define your own factories for `Matrix` and `Row`:

```
object TestMatrix extends App{  
  type Row = List[Int]
  def Row(xs: Int*) = List(xs: _*)

  type Matrix = List[Row]
  def Matrix(xs: Row*) = List(xs: _*)

  val m = Matrix( Row(1,2,3),
      Row(1,2,3),
      Row(1,2,3)
      )
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks.  That's also cleared up what apply does as well.

Comment: Just a small note that if you explicitly specify the return type for the factory functions (i.e. `def Matrix(xs: Row*): Matrix = List(xs: _*)`) you will (perhaps obviously) help the compiler/type checker see the result as a `Matrix` instead of a `List[Row]`. Defining `Matrix` as an object with an `apply` method identical to the shown `Matrix` factory method also works, of course.

Answer (score 5):

From [this](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/package_objects.html) article you have.

> Note also that along with most of the type aliases in package scala
>   comes a value alias of the same name. For instance, there's a type
>   alias for the List class and a value alias for the List object.

A solution to the problem translates to:

```
object TestMatrix extends App{  
  type Row = List[Int]
  val Row = List
  type Matrix = List[Row]
  val Matrix = List

  val m = Matrix( Row(1,2,3),
                  Row(1,2,3),
                  Row(1,2,3))
}
```

Comment: While this is the common solution to the problem, it is not appropriate here because the type alias fixes the type parameters (to `Int` and `Row`). By example your code allows to do `Matrix( "aze", 123 )` (returning a `List[Any]`, which clearly is **not** the same type as `Matrix`), which is certainly not the expected behaviour.