# Type aliases that work in the REPL but not in a scala class/object

Tags: scala, types

I have a testing program in which we have in memory static arrays. I am using type aliases for brevity.

The following works in the REPL

```
type >[T] = Array[T]
val dat = >(>(1,2,3),>(2,3,4))

dat: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4))
```

However changing the identifier to "A" from ">" does *not* work: the type is created but the same syntax for creating the array as used above fails:

```
scala> type A[T] = Array[T]
defined type alias A

scala> val dat = A(A(1,2,3),A(2,3,4))
<console>:7: error: not found: value A
       val dat = A(A(1,2,3),A(2,3,4))
```

Also, NEITHER of the two above work within a Scala program AFAICT:

```
  test("VectorProjection") {
    type  A[T] = Array[T]
    // Next line shows RED for all the A's and also has compiler error: "not found: value A"
    val dat  = A(A(1., 2., 3.), A(1.5,2.,2.5), A(2.,3.8,5.6), A(2.5,3.0,3.5), A(3.1,3.7,4.3) )
    val firsteigen =  subtractProject(dat(0), dat(4))
  }
```

Looking for:

- 1) For the REPL: An explanation of why the symbol ">" works but not
  the identifier would be helpful.
- 2) For a real scala program/class:
  An explanation of if it were possible to use any syntax similar to
  the above

**UPDATE** Per suggestion by James Iry the following approach does work :

```
    def A[T : ClassTag](ts: T*) = Array(ts:_*)
```

Here it is in action:

```
  test("VectorProjection") {
    def A[T : ClassTag](ts: T*) = Array(ts:_*)
    val dat  = A(
      A(1., 2., 3.),
      A(1.5,2.,2.5),
      A(3.,6.,9.)  )
    val firstEigen =  subtractProject(dat(0), dat(5))
    println(s"firstEigen: ${firstEigen.mkString(",")}")
  }
```

**Another UPDATE**  Another answer hits closer to this OP:

Use type and val together:

```
    type A = Array[Double]
    val A = Array
```

Here it is in action:

```
  test("VectorProjection") {
    type A = Array[Double]
    val A = Array
    val dat  = A(
      A(1., 2., 3.),
      A(1.5,2.,2.5),
      A(3.,6.,9.)  )
    val firstEigen =  subtractProject(dat(0), dat(5))
    println(s"firstEigen: ${firstEigen.mkString(",")}")
  }
```

Comment: What version of scala are you using ? Your first example doesn't work for me (scala 2.11.2) (and afaik doesn't/shouldn't work with any version). As for why, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15784052/2650437).

Comment: @Marth  scala 2.10.4

Comment: Everyone wants to know how you borked your repl session.

Comment: By borked I mean, you got your REPL into a state we can't reproduce. It would be nice to diagnose that. REPL history is a lot of state, and it can produce deceptive results; comment your code `// show` to show what your code compiles to, including imports from history. BTW, Iry's answer is right; you're not saying your first example works, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a value alias it will work:

```
type A[T] = Array[T]
val A = Array
val dat = A(A(1,2,3),A(2,3,4)) //dat: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4))
```

Line 2 creates a value alias, so you can create values with `A` type alias. It will in turn be able to call A.apply(1,2,3).

Comment: I chose this answer as the correct one because it is most directly responding to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to replicate your success with '>'

```
scala> type >[T]=Array[T]
defined type alias $greater

scala> >(1,2,3)
<console>:8: error: not found: value >
              >(1,2,3)
              ^
```

At least, not until I define it

```
scala> import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect._

scala> def >[T : ClassTag](ts: T*) = Array(ts:_*)
$greater: [T](ts: T*)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]

scala> >(1,2,3)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Same thing works for A

```
scala> type A[T]=Array[T]
defined type alias A

scala> A(1,2,3)
<console>:11: error: not found: value A
              A(1,2,3)
              ^

scala> def A[T : ClassTag](ts: T*) = Array(ts:_*)
A: [T](ts: T*)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]

scala> A(1,2,3)
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

For an explanation: type X = Y just creates a synonym for the type X. It doesn't bring in synonyms for everything else that might be associated with the type like companion objects, constructor methods, etc.

Comment: Interesting you are not able to reproduce the REPL success. I took your code (not assigning to a variable expicitly) and it also worked. But to the main event here: I like your def and will try it in a real program.

Comment: I originally awarded this answer but another one came just moments later that is more precise answer to the OP. This question is in any case helpful and I upvoted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to show what the repl knows:

```
scala> $intp.definedTerms
res0: List[$intp.global.TermName] = List($intp)

scala> $intp.definedTypes
res1: List[$intp.global.TypeName] = List($greater)
```

E.g., you might have:

```
scala> object X
defined object X

scala> trait X
defined trait X
warning: previously defined object X is not a companion to trait X.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.

scala> type X = String
defined type alias X
```

But it doesn't warn on aliasing.

Comment: Thanks that is useful info.